# Is Bridj recommended for OpenCV?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, bridj

I have been looking around for wrapping up my C++/OpenCV code and move it to Android.

So far JNI, JNA, JNAerator, SWIG etc I found somewhat Bridj a bit more easier to understand and use. Is Bridj a good binding for my OpenCV source code for Android? I could not find good samples explaining anything about wrapping OpenCV/C++ for Android and at this moment I am not sure if I should use Bridj.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own wrapper. There is [OpenCV Java](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html). Here is the [introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html).

Good luck!

Comment: He might need it if he has a large code base in C++ for which he does not want to manually convert to Java. Also you suggested OpenCV Java which is for desktops. For Android there is the specific OpenCV-Android.